# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError"

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wanted to implement image notification in a flutter app. I setup everything using [this doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#advanced-optional-allowing-notification-images) and when I run a real device, the image notification worked. ​

but, when i try to Archive the build i'm getting this error. I am able to take archive only if I delete the MyImageNotification target.

[image]

This is folder structure looks like once i completed setup of imagg notification
[image]

I got below message from the bottom of the error log

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Flutter'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterError", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_dynamic_links(FLTFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_dynamic_links(FLTFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_messaging(FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.o)
  "_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseCorePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_dynamic_links(FLTFirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.o)
      -[FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in firebase_messaging(FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My PodFile look like this

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
'Debug' => :debug,
'Profile' => :release,
'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
 raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end

File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
 matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
 return matches[1].strip if matches
end
raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
 flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
end
end

target 'MyImageNotification' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Comment: do you use build flavors?

Comment: yes. i do @lesha-native

Comment: @lesha-native  I have added some error. that might help to understand better

Answer (score 3):

**Possible solution #1**

Try inside ios folder:

1. rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock .symlinks Flutter/Flutter.podspec Runner.xcworkspace
2. pod repo update
3. pod install
4. Run archive

**Possible solution #2**

If steps above won't help, please ensure that your "Build Active Architecture Only" for target flavor is set to "no"

[image]

**Possible solution #3**

The idea is to bump target ios version. In your podfile set:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

And modify your post install script the next way:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Then reinstall pods (`pod deintegrate`, `pod install`)

Comment: Thanks. tried those two ways. but, did not work.

Comment: I assume there is something wrong with arch. setup. i cant find though

Comment: also, the third way is not working.  build can be archived when I delete MyImageNotification file. with image notification i cant archive it

Answer (score 1):

looks like similer issue please  : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95256